# DMI3 shows speed unknown

Tags: lspci

I used "lspci -s 00:00.0 -vv" to dump DMI3 status, and the LnkSta shows speed unknown.
LnkSta is Link status register and means current speed. But it's speed unknown.
Does it be abnormal about speed unknown?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Find the capability pointer of DMI3, it doesn't support SW. So this is not problem.

[image: DMI capability pointer]